# JanusGraph container fails to start when setting the allow-custom-vid-types

Tags: graph, janusgraph

I can spin up a container of janusgraph/janusgraph locally using docker compose.
Everything is fine until I set the `allow-custom-vid-types` env to true, which makes the container **fail to start** with the following log

```
2023-12-14 16:08:29 waiting for storage...
2023-12-14 16:08:44 waiting for storage...
2023-12-14 16:09:00 waiting for storage...
2023-12-14 16:09:15 waiting for storage...
2023-12-14 16:09:19 /etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph-server.yaml will be used to start JanusGraph Server in foreground
2023-12-14 16:09:21 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
2023-12-14 16:09:21 SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.20.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2023-12-14 16:09:21 SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph/lib/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2023-12-14 16:09:21 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2023-12-14 16:09:21 SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.printHeader -                                                                       
2023-12-14 16:09:21    mmm                                mmm                       #     
2023-12-14 16:09:21      #   mmm   m mm   m   m   mmm   m"   "  m mm   mmm   mmmm   # mm  
2023-12-14 16:09:21      #  "   #  #"  #  #   #  #   "  #   mm  #"  " "   #  #" "#  #"  # 
2023-12-14 16:09:21      #  m"""#  #   #  #   #   """m  #    #  #     m"""#  #   #  #   # 
2023-12-14 16:09:21  "mmm"  "mm"#  #   #  "mm"#  "mmm"   "mmm"  #     "mm"#  ##m#"  #   # 
2023-12-14 16:09:21                                                          #            
2023-12-14 16:09:21                                                          "            
2023-12-14 16:09:21 
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  com.jcabi.log.Logger.infoForced - 106 attributes loaded from 339 stream(s) in 51ms, 106 saved, 5377 ignored: ["Agent-Class", "Ant-Version", "Archiver-Version", "Automatic-Module-Name", "Bnd-LastModified", "Build-Date", "Build-Date-UTC", "Build-Id", "Build-Java-Version", "Build-Jdk", "Build-Jdk-Spec", "Build-Number", "Build-Tag", "Build-Timezone", "Build-Version", "Built-By", "Built-JDK", "Built-OS", "Built-Status", "Bundle-ActivationPolicy", "Bundle-Activator", "Bundle-Category", "Bundle-ClassPath", "Bundle-Classpath", "Bundle-ContactAddress", "Bundle-Copyright", "Bundle-Description", "Bundle-Developers", "Bundle-DocURL", "Bundle-License", "Bundle-ManifestVersion", "Bundle-Name", "Bundle-NativeCode", "Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment", "Bundle-SCM", "Bundle-SymbolicName", "Bundle-Vendor", "Bundle-Version", "Can-Redefine-Classes", "Can-Retransform-Classes", "Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix", "Carl-Is-Awesome", "Change", "Copyright", "Created-By", "DSTAMP", "Dependencies", "DynamicImport-Package", "Eclipse-BuddyPolicy", "Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI", "Embed-Dependency", "Embed-Transitive", "Export-Package", "Extension-Name", "Extension-name", "Fragment-Host", "Gradle-Version", "Gremlin-Plugin-Dependencies", "Ignore-Package", "Implementation-Build", "Implementation-Build-Date", "Implementation-Build-Id", "Implementation-Title", "Implementation-URL", "Implementation-Vendor", "Implementation-Vendor-Id", "Implementation-Version", "Import-Package", "Include-Resource", "JCabi-Build", "JCabi-Date", "JCabi-Version", "Main-Class", "Manifest-Version", "Module-Origin", "Module-Requires", "Multi-Release", "Originally-Created-By", "Package", "Premain-Class", "Private-Package", "Provide-Capability", "Require-Bundle", "Require-Capability", "Sealed", "Specification-Title", "Specification-Vendor", "Specification-Version", "TODAY", "TSTAMP", "Target-Label", "Tool", "X-Compile-Elasticsearch-Snapshot", "X-Compile-Elasticsearch-Version", "X-Compile-Lucene-Version", "X-Compile-Source-JDK", "X-Compile-Target-JDK", "artifactId", "groupId", "hash", "janusgraphVersion", "service", "tinkerpop-version", "tinkerpopVersion", "url", "version"]
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.printHeader - JanusGraph Version: 1.0.0
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.printHeader - TinkerPop Version: 3.7.0
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.start - Configuring JanusGraph Server from /etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph-server.yaml
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager.addConsoleReporter - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager.addCsvReporter - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager.addJmxReporter - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager.addSlf4jReporter - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
2023-12-14 16:09:21 16:09:21 INFO  org.apache.commons.beanutils.FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector.introspect - Error when creating PropertyDescriptor for public final void org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)! Ignoring this property.
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init> - Could not invoke constructor on class org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager (defined by the 'graphManager' setting) with one argument of class Settings
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 ERROR org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.lambda$main$0 - JanusGraph Server was unable to start and will now begin shutdown
2023-12-14 16:09:22 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:97) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:127) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:90) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.start(JanusGraphServer.java:85) ~[janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.main(JanusGraphServer.java:53) [janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:86) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     ... 4 more
2023-12-14 16:09:22 Caused by: org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: allow-custom-vid-types is not supported for OrderedKeyValueStore
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:513) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:64) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.lambda$open$0(JanusGraphFactory.java:165) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.openGraph(JanusGraphManager.java:239) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:165) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:115) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.lambda$new$0(JanusGraphManager.java:73) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.<init>(JanusGraphManager.java:72) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:86) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
2023-12-14 16:09:22     ... 4 more
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader.lambda$static$0 - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader.lambda$static$0 - Adding the session OpProcessor.
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader.lambda$static$0 - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$2 - Shutting down OpProcessor[]
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$2 - Shutting down OpProcessor[session]
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$2 - Shutting down OpProcessor[traversal]
2023-12-14 16:09:22 16:09:22 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.stop - Shutting down thread pools.
2023-12-14 16:09:24 12/14/23, 4:09:24 PM ===========================================================
2023-12-14 16:09:24 
2023-12-14 16:09:24 -- Gauges ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-12-14 16:09:24 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.sessions
2023-12-14 16:09:24              value = 0
2023-12-14 16:09:24 
2023-12-14 16:09:24 -- Timers ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-12-14 16:09:24 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.op.eval
2023-12-14 16:09:24              count = 0
2023-12-14 16:09:24          mean rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24      1-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24      5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24     15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24                min = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24                max = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               mean = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24             stddev = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24             median = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               75% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               95% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               98% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               99% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24             99.9% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.op.traversal
2023-12-14 16:09:24              count = 0
2023-12-14 16:09:24          mean rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24      1-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24      5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24     15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
2023-12-14 16:09:24                min = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24                max = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               mean = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24             stddev = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24             median = 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               75% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               95% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               98% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24               99% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24             99.9% <= 0.00 milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24 
2023-12-14 16:09:24 
2023-12-14 16:09:24 16:09:24 INFO  com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter$InfoLoggerProxy.log - type=GAUGE, name=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.sessions, value=0
2023-12-14 16:09:24 16:09:24 INFO  com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter$InfoLoggerProxy.log - type=TIMER, name=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.op.eval, count=0, min=0.0, max=0.0, mean=0.0, stddev=0.0, p50=0.0, p75=0.0, p95=0.0, p98=0.0, p99=0.0, p999=0.0, m1_rate=0.0, m5_rate=0.0, m15_rate=0.0, mean_rate=0.0, rate_unit=events/second, duration_unit=milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24 16:09:24 INFO  com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter$InfoLoggerProxy.log - type=TIMER, name=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.op.traversal, count=0, min=0.0, max=0.0, mean=0.0, stddev=0.0, p50=0.0, p75=0.0, p95=0.0, p98=0.0, p99=0.0, p999=0.0, m1_rate=0.0, m5_rate=0.0, m15_rate=0.0, mean_rate=0.0, rate_unit=events/second, duration_unit=milliseconds
2023-12-14 16:09:24 16:09:24 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$9 - Gremlin Server - shutdown complete
```

You can see the logs shows an initial long delay on `waiting for storage...` step which only happens when I pass the `allow-custom-vid-types=true` to the container.

#### The docker compose I use

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  graph:
    image: janusgraph/janusgraph
    environment:
       janusgraph.graph.set-vertex-id: true
       janusgraph.graph.allow-custom-vid-types: true
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
```

#### Environment

- **OS:** macOS 14.1.2 (23B92)*
- **Chip:** Apple M1 Pro
- **Docker Desktop:** 4.25.2(129061)

Comment: What kind of storage backend are you using with JanusGraph and what is the Janusgraph version are you using? I have recently tried the custom id feature with janusgraph 1.0 by using Apache Cassandra as the storage backend it was working successfully

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests `allow-custom-vid-types is not supported for OrderedKeyValueStore`.

As for JanusGraph 1.0.0 `BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore` implements `OrderedKeyValueStore` which means that custom vertex id types cannot be used with `Berkeley DB` database.
JanusGraph docker image (1.0.0) by default uses `Berkeley DB` storage option (as noted in the [JanusGraph Docker Overview](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph)).

In your situation you need to specify another storage backend to be used with  JanusGraph instead of using the default file-based storage option. However, it will require you to setting up your storage backend (i.e. so that it's available on the configured storage host and port).
You may choose Cassandra, HBase, ScyllaDB, Bigtable or any of the provided storage adapters to use `allow-custom-vid-types` option.

To fix your example you could use a similar docker file as shown in JanusGraph + Cassandra + ElasticSearch docker compose file ([here](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/docker/examples/docker-compose-cql-es.yml)). However, as you don't need ElasticSearch you can use `JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cql` instead of `JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cql-es`.

Complete docker-compose file with Cassandra + JanusGraph and activated custom vertex ID types could looks something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  janusgraph:
    image: docker.io/janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
    container_name: jce-janusgraph
    environment:
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cql
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: jce-cassandra
      janusgraph.graph.allow-custom-vid-types: "true"
      janusgraph.graph.set-vertex-id: "true"
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      cassandra:
        condition: service_started

  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3
    container_name: jce-cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    networks:
      - jce-network

networks:
  jce-network:
volumes:
  janusgraph-default-data:
```

See more information about the JanusGraph Docker Container (configuration, usages, etc.) in the documentation: https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/container/